# EXCEL end result is showing 1 when supposed to be blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, tie

im creating a recreational spreadsheet to keep track of my soccer league standings.

Here is my problem....(IN BOLD)

HOME/AWAY    OPPONENT     GOALS FOR     GOALS AGAINST                         W    T    L

```
H           RED           4              2    1    
A           RED           1              3        1
                                                1
                                                1
                                                1
```

(and so on...)

Im using a formula for Ties --->    =if(c5=d5,1,0)

what changes should i make for the end result to be blank until I enter a value in the goals for/against column.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now, I have a seperate table(s) to categorize home performances and away performances, how do i create that formula...

if home, and a win, put 1 if not put 0
if home, and a tie, put 1 if not put 0
if home, and a loss, put 1 if not put 0

if away...yada yada yada...

basically i have this formula (which doesnt work...    =if(a1="h",1,0)     

**how do i also calculate the score into that formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isblank to test for an empty cell and a pair of speech marks ("") to show nothing in a cell until the logical test is true.

eg

=IF(OR(ISBLANK(c5),ISBLANK(d5)),"",IF(c5=d5,1,0))

That will keep the result from showing until both the scores have been entered

Wing

Comment: Now, I have a seperate table(s) to categorize home performances and away performances, how do i create that formula... 

if home, and a win, put 1 if not put 0 
if home, and a tie, put 1 if not put 0 
if home, and a loss, put 1 if not put 0 

if away...yada yada yada... 

basically i have this formula (which doesnt work... 

=if(a1="h",1,0) 

**how do i also calculate the score into that formula